# How to update config based on envronment for middleman s3_sync?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, bundler, middleman

I'm trying to push slate docs to 2 different S3 buckets based on the environment.
But it's complaining that s3_sync is not a parameter for middleman.

I have mentioned the S3 bucket in the environment using config.rb but still I'm getting the above issue when I run `bundle exec middleman s3_sync --verbose --environment=internal`

**config.rb:**

```
configure :internal do
  s3_sync.bucket                     = ENV['INTERNAL_DOCS_AWS_BUCKET'] # The name of the internal docs S3 bucket you are targeting. This is globally unique.
end

activate :s3_sync do |s3_sync|
  s3_sync.bucket                     = ENV['DOCS_AWS_BUCKET'] # The name of the S3 bucket you are targeting. This is globally unique.
  s3_sync.region                     = ENV['DOCS_AWS_REGION']     # The AWS region for your bucket.
  s3_sync.aws_access_key_id          = ENV['DOCS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  s3_sync.aws_secret_access_key      = ENV['DOCS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  s3_sync.prefer_gzip                = true
  s3_sync.path_style                 = true
  s3_sync.reduced_redundancy_storage = false
  s3_sync.acl                        = 'public-read'
  s3_sync.encryption                 = false
  s3_sync.prefix                     = ''
  s3_sync.version_bucket             = false
  s3_sync.index_document             = 'index.html'
  s3_sync.error_document             = '404.html'
end
```

**Error:**

> bundler: failed to load command: middleman
> (/usr/local/bundle/bin/middleman) NameError: undefined local variable
> or method `s3_sync' for #Middleman::ConfigContext:0x0000561eca099a40

Answer (score 0):

`s3_sync` is only defined within the block of `activate :s3_sync`.
It is undefined within the `configure :internal` block.

A solution might look like the following, using [`environment?`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Application#environment%3F-instance_method) or [`environment`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Application#environment-instance_method)

```rb
activate :s3_sync do |s3_sync|
  s3_sync.bucket = if environment?(:internal)
                     ENV['INTERNAL_DOCS_AWS_BUCKET']
                   else
                     ENV['DOCS_AWS_BUCKET']
                   end
  s3_sync.region = ENV['DOCS_AWS_REGION']
  # ...
end
```